# React Native navigation on successful api response

Tags: javascript, react-native

just wanted to ask about the possible ways to navigate to a screen upon a successful api response in react native..
I have been using redux for state management in projects.

I have tried a few ways and would like suggestions of good practice from you all.

1. using useEffect hook with a dependency.
2. passing the navigation object in the action and call it on the successful .then result.
3. using promises like

```
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000);
//api call here
});

promise.then(
  result => alert(result), //navigation login
  error => alert(error) // error handling
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use useNavigation hooks to navigate to a particular screen.

```
const navigation = useNavigation();

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000);
//api call here
});

promise.then(
  result => navigation.navigate('OtherScree',{
  result:result}), //navigation login
  error => alert(error) // error handling
);
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help buddy , useNavigation can be used for sure, when we don't have the navigation object .

but that is a way " how to navigate to other screens "
usenavigation is the answer to that

but what I want to know is "how to navigate on a successful api response  ?"
--means ways when we get a 200 then to navigate to other screens

Comment: if you have any other alternative to this , please share